# pdf creation on Android: what is the difference between PdfDocument and PdfPrintedDocument

Tags: java, android, kotlin, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to create a pdf file in my Android app.

What is the difference between these two classes ?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html

Thanks !